# How To Display ALL image from Server folder in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have written code that so far only displays the name of the all image files, but not actually show the images in my JSP page. I get the project path and also the image name from the folder. I have the image in the same folder as abc.jsp. This folder was created by me and in it I have placed some image files

```
//file name t.java
//IMPORTED PACKAGES

@WebServlet("/t")
public class t extends HttpServlet
{
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("TEXT/HTML");
        String path=request.getServletContext().getRealPath("ne");
        File folder = new File(path);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
            {
              if (listOfFiles[i].isFile())
              {
                  if(listOfFiles[i].getName().equals("abc.jpg"))
                {
                    out.println("match ===="+listOfFiles[i].getName());

                    out.print("<img src='"+listOfFiles[i]+"' width='242' height='242' />");
                }}
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("file not found");
                }}}}
```

//here is html file

---

```
//jsp file to call servlet file 
<html>
<body>
<form action="t" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="name"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

also change the content type but not show image

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're expecting this to do. Could you explain what output you're receiving vs. what output you're expecting?

Comment: sir i upload image files server folder and rename by fetch ID of employee stored in database and want to retrieve these store image by match image name by user ID want to display with session currenlty login user name with their photo and  also want to generate the ID-CARD for the employee so i want to retrieve image by name if image name match with current login USER ID then show it only match name show

Answer (score 0):

Store your images in folder in your project like
/web-content/images/{All images is there} and store link to this path in your database or in a liste, the URL is PC:port/YourProject/images/images1.jpg in your get methode, you need to add URL in a List and recovered the value in JSP file like